# C# WPF Code Stops when creating stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I'm trying to add a feature to where, when a new key-value pair in a network table is added, it will add a new stackpanel with the new data. However, when running the code, using breakpoints, the code just stops silently, no crashing or anything, just stops. The code stops right at the creation of the StackPanel object.

```
public void ValueChanged(ITable source, string key, Value value, NotifyFlags flags)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case @"AUTON_OPTIONS":
                updateAutonOptions(value.GetStringArray());
                break;
            case @"POSITION_OPTIONS":
                updatePositionOptions(value.GetStringArray());
                break;
            case @"AUTON_FOUND":
                updateAutonFound(value.GetString());
                break;
            default:
                StackPanel formItem = null;
                RobotData.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
                {
                    formItem = (StackPanel)RobotData.FindName(key);
                });
                if(formItem == null)
                {
                    StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel
                    {
                        Name = key,
                        Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
                    }; //new stackpanel for new data type

                    Label label = new Label
                    {
                        Content = key
                    }; //new label for key name
                    TextBox textBox = new TextBox
                    {
                        IsEnabled = false,
                        Text = value.GetString()
                    }; //new textbox for value data

                    stackPanel.Children.Add(label); //add label to new stackpanel
                    stackPanel.Children.Add(textBox); //add textbox to new stackpanel
                    RobotData.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        RobotData.Children.Add(stackPanel);//add new stackpanel to RobotData stackpanel (declared in xaml) 
                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    foreach(Object o in ((StackPanel)formItem).Children)
                    {
                        if(o is TextBox)
                        {
                            ((TextBox)o).Text = value.GetString();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: @ChirsWeeks instead of assigning to StackPanel Object just assign it to variable made by var.  
`var obj= (StackPanel)RobotData.FindName(key);` By this you can understand what is present in it. Not sure what is present in the value of the RobotData Object.

Comment: The fact that `RobotData.FindName` is wrapped in a `Dispatcher.Invoke` call seems to indicate that your code runs outside the UI thread. If that is the case, be aware that creating and later accessing a StackPanel must also be done in the UI thread, i.e. also be wrapped by `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue thanks to help from a friend, as well as the two commenters above! thank you both! Here is the code that works:

```
public void ValueChanged(ITable source, string key, Value value, NotifyFlags flags)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case @"AUTON_OPTIONS":
                updateAutonOptions(value.GetStringArray());
                break;
            case @"POSITION_OPTIONS":
                updatePositionOptions(value.GetStringArray());
                break;
            case @"AUTON_FOUND":
                updateAutonFound(value.GetString());
                break;
            default:
                //StackPanel formItem = null;
                RobotData.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    var formItem = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(RobotData, key);
                    //});
                    if (formItem == null)
                    {

                        //Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        //{
                        StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel
                        {
                            Name = key,
                            Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
                        }; //new stackpanel for new data type

                        Label label = new Label
                        {
                            Content = key
                        }; //new label for key name
                        TextBox textBox = new TextBox
                        {
                            IsReadOnly = true,
                            Text = value.GetObjectValue().ToString()
                        }; //new textbox for value data

                        stackPanel.Children.Add(label); //add label to new stackpanel
                        stackPanel.Children.Add(textBox); //add textbox to new stackpanel
                        RobotData.Children.Add(stackPanel);//add new stackpanel to RobotData stackpanel (declared in xaml) 
                                                           //});

                    }

                   else
                   {
                       foreach(Object o in ((StackPanel)formItem).Children)
                       {
                           if(o is TextBox)
                           {
                               ((TextBox)o).Text = value.GetString();
                               break;
                           }
                       }
                   }
                });
                break;

        }
    }
```